# Write/Read NDEF message multiple time to a tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I'm sending a NDEF message to a microcontroller. Write and read are working fine for only one write/read (but not both in the same time).
It's similar like this: [Write NDEF message multiple times to same tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956641/write-ndef-message-multiple-times-to-same-tag) but that didn't helped.

My code is:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(detectedTag);
            try {
                ndef.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("connect", "Connection error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(getNdefMessage("Hey"));
                Log.e("write", "write ok");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("write", "error write "+e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(getNdefMessage("Hey"));
                Log.e("write", "write ok");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("write", "error write "+e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(getNdefMessage("Hey"));
                Log.e("write", "write ok");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("write", "error write "+e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                ndef.writeNdefMessage(getNdefMessage("Hey"));
                Log.e("write", "write ok");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("write", "error write "+e.getMessage());
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    ndef.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("write", "ndef close");
                }
            }
 }
        }).start();
```

If I want to write 4 times, first one is ok, after that last 3 are errors.
logcat:

```
08-27 10:11:45.029  12850-12850/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ write ok
08-27 10:11:45.299  12850-12850/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ error write Tag is not ndef
08-27 10:11:45.379  12850-12850/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ error write Tag is not ndef
08-27 10:11:45.459  12850-12850/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ error write Tag is not ndef
```

Replacing `writeNdefMessage()` with `getNdefMessage()` for read it works...

Logcat:

```
08-27 10:25:26.584  24701-24701/com.example.me.testnfc E/Read﹕ Read ok
08-27 10:25:26.646  24701-24701/com.example.me.testnfc E/Read﹕ Read ok
08-27 10:25:26.709  24701-24701/com.example.me.testnfc E/Read﹕ Read ok
08-27 10:25:26.783  24701-24701/com.example.me.testnfc E/Read﹕ Read ok
```

EDIT:  added a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after every write, and a `Log.e("Detected TAG", detectedTag.toString())` in `onNewIntent()`
Logcat:

```
08-27 10:50:57.988  15948-15948/com.example.me.testnfc E/Detected TAG﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
08-27 10:51:00.461  15948-16128/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ write ok
08-27 10:51:02.221  15948-15948/com.example.me.testnfc E/Detected TAG﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
08-27 10:51:02.533  15948-16128/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ write ok
08-27 10:51:04.312  15948-15948/com.example.me.testnfc E/Detected TAG﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
08-27 10:51:04.620  15948-16128/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ write ok
08-27 10:51:06.405  15948-15948/com.example.me.testnfc E/Detected TAG﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
08-27 10:51:06.692  15948-16128/com.example.me.testnfc E/write﹕ write ok
08-27 10:51:08.480  15948-15948/com.example.me.testnfc E/Detected TAG﹕ TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.Ndef]
```

Comment: From you log it appears that wait just 80ms before the next write starts. You may try to wait a bit before the next attempt to give the chip time to complete the internal writing prozess.

Comment: added a `Thread.sleep(1000)` after every `writeNdefMessage()` same issue...

Comment: @corvairjo  edited OP with your advice

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. Your logcat shows now "write OK", while it it had been "error write Tag..." before.

Comment: @corvairjo I added a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after every write... That's why it's writing ok. But I want to do it without waiting two seconds.